# What is the advantage of using library('tidyverse') instead of sub packages?

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I was wondering what could be the impact on a large `R` (`shiny`) application if we call the `tidyverse` package. We usually call `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and so on separately. Any hints are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a shorthand to have all those libraries packaged in one. It also prevents issues of functions from one tidyverse library being masked by functions in another tidyverse library. This has been a problem with the order in which you load plyr and dplyr

Comment: I had the problem recently of missing up those functions with the same name. Thanks for this comment :). Now things make more sense, it was so hard to debug :)

Comment: In fact it’s a huge anti-pattern, **don’t do this**. Load packages explicitly only if you need them. Don’t load packages you don’t need. Matt’s answer gives some reasons for why this is but more fundamentally it’s a bad idea because it removes explicitness and control from the code, and the only benefit is minimal convenience.

Answer (score 22):

> Update: As of May 14th, 2020, recursive dependency count is now up to 101.

The `tidyverse` package currently has 87 dependencies.

1. Loading all of them will slightly increase your application's start-up time,
2. If you're using `packrat`, you now have to save copies of 87 packages in your local library. If you're not using `packrat`, something will *probably* get updated and break your shiny app within 6 months.

If you're at all concerned about performance and maintaining this application long term I'd recommend minimizing dependencies and only loading the packages you actually use.

```
sort(tools::package_dependencies(package="tidyverse", recursive=TRUE)$tidyverse)

#   [1] "askpass"      "assertthat"   "backports"   
#   [4] "base64enc"    "BH"           "broom"       
#   [7] "callr"        "cellranger"   "cli"         
#  [10] "clipr"        "colorspace"   "crayon"      
#  [13] "curl"         "DBI"          "dbplyr"      
#  [16] "desc"         "digest"       "dplyr"       
#  [19] "ellipsis"     "evaluate"     "fansi"       
#  [22] "farver"       "forcats"      "fs"          
#  [25] "generics"     "ggplot2"      "glue"        
#  [28] "graphics"     "grDevices"    "grid"        
#  [31] "gtable"       "haven"        "highr"       
#  [34] "hms"          "htmltools"    "httr"        
#  [37] "isoband"      "jsonlite"     "knitr"       
#  [40] "labeling"     "lattice"      "lifecycle"   
#  [43] "lubridate"    "magrittr"     "markdown"    
#  [46] "MASS"         "Matrix"       "methods"     
#  [49] "mgcv"         "mime"         "modelr"      
#  [52] "munsell"      "nlme"         "openssl"     
#  [55] "pillar"       "pkgbuild"     "pkgconfig"   
#  [58] "pkgload"      "plogr"        "plyr"        
#  [61] "praise"       "prettyunits"  "processx"    
#  [64] "progress"     "ps"           "purrr"       
#  [67] "R6"           "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"        
#  [70] "readr"        "readxl"       "rematch"     
#  [73] "reprex"       "reshape2"     "rlang"       
#  [76] "rmarkdown"    "rprojroot"    "rstudioapi"  
#  [79] "rvest"        "scales"       "selectr"     
#  [82] "splines"      "stats"        "stringi"     
#  [85] "stringr"      "sys"          "testthat"    
#  [88] "tibble"       "tidyr"        "tidyselect"  
#  [91] "tinytex"      "tools"        "utf8"        
#  [94] "utils"        "vctrs"        "viridisLite" 
#  [97] "whisker"      "withr"        "xfun"        
# [100] "xml2"         "yaml"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn´t know that command as I needed that for verifying other packages. Thanks for sharing.